# How do you run Jenkins job traffic through a proxy?

Tags: jenkins, proxy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that uses a Jenkinsfile and groovy script to do a build.

During the testing/scanning phase I would like to send all traffic through a proxy, specifically right before the groovy script does `sh "npm run test"`.

Is there a way to specify a proxy url and port right before I run the tests so all traffic from that job goes through it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy) you can specify `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. In Jenkins scripted pipeline you can do it this way

```
withEnv(['HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyAddress:port']) {
    sh "npm run test"
}
```

If you use declarative pipeline you need  `environment { }` block

```
environment { 
    HTTP_PROXY = 'http://proxyAddress:port'
}
```